# What is a set of generators for the multiplicative group of rationals?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to think of a set of generators for the group $(\mathbb{Q^\times, *})$, which I think is countably generated (as opposed to finitely generated). (I wonder if such a set could be the primes of $\mathbb{Z}$ (together with $1$ and $-1),$ meaning the set $\{1, -1, \frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}, ...\}$ generates all nonzero rationals?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume your list continues on $\{\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{5},-\frac{1}{5}, \ldots\}$.

You do indeed give a list of generators; but your list is redundant:

- $1$ is contained in every group; it need not be listed
- $-\frac{1}{2} = (-1) \cdot \frac{1}{2}$, so you only need to include one of each associate; it's traditional to take the positive one in your list and remove the negative one.

Also, it's traditional to list the *primes* as the generators, rather than their inverses. That is, the typical set of generators one uses for $\mathbb{Q}^\times$ is the set

$$ \{ -1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, \ldots \} $$

This is a minimal set of generators; the only relationship between its elements is

$$(-1) = (-1)^{-1}$$

Answer (score 14):

You're quite right: $(\mathbb{Q^\times, *})$ is generated by the (positive) primes and $-1$:
$$
\mathbb{Q}^\times \cong C_2 \times \bigoplus_p \mathbb Z
$$

This is essentially the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: And the uniqueness asserted by the F.T.A. essentially says that $(\Bbb Q^{\times}, \ast)$ is *freely* generated by the primes, giving a canonical identification of that group with (since there are countably many primes) $\left(\bigoplus_{\textrm{$p$ prime}} \Bbb Z, +\right)$.

Comment: @Travis: Up to the roots of unity you're forgetting about.

Comment: @Travis I was about to ask if this was the minimal generating set. I guess it is, then?

Comment: @Hurkyl Oops, you're right, of course: That statement applies to $\Bbb Q^+$, not $\Bbb Q^{\times}$. To get all of $\Bbb Q^{\times}$ you need to throw in some negative number. Then, the element $-1$ generates a torsion subgroup, and the canonical identification is with $\left((\Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z) \oplus \bigoplus_{\textrm{$p$ prime}} \Bbb Z, +\right)$.

Comment: @Travis Also, what does $\bigoplus_p\mathbb{Z}$ mean? What group is that? Or could you mean $\bigoplus_p \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @étale-cohomology It just means a countable sum of copies of $\Bbb Z$ indexed by primes. One can write any positive rational $q$ uniquely as $2^{n_2} 3^{n_3} 5^{n_5} \cdots$ for finitely many nonzero $n_a$. Then, this identification maps $q$ to $(n_2, n_3, n_5, \ldots) \in \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z \oplus \cdots)$, and it's straightforward to check that multiplication of rational numbers corresponds to the usual addition of sequences.

Comment: @étale-cohomology it means a direct sum over all primes where *each* "summand" is the integers. This is correct.

Comment: And yes, this generating set (of $\Bbb Q^+)$ is minimal. No prime can be expressed as a product and quotient of other primes, so no generator can be omitted.