# Is the multiplicative group $\mathbb Q\backslash\{0\}$ a free module over $\mathbb Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm trying to decide whether the multiplicative group of nonzero rational numbers is a free module over the integers or not. It is the second part of a question from Musili's *Introduction to rings and modules*. The first one, which I could solve, is:

> Show that the multiplicative group of positive rational numbers,
>   considered as a module over $\mathbb Z$, is a free module with the set
>   of all positive prime numbers as a basis.

My attempt was unimportant. Since $\mathbb Z$ is PID, I've looked for a nonfree submodule, my bet being the negative. On another hand, I've tried to find a basis. My guess is that this basis doesn't exist, but I could not prove it. I'd be glad if someone could help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't you just have to show a product of powers of primes cannot equal one unless all powers are zero?  Or something like that?

Comment: The question body is about positive rationals, the title about non-zero rationals - that's a great differenece

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2233946/what-is-a-set-of-generators-for-the-multiplicative-group-of-rationals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement that $\mathbb Q_{>0}^\times$ considered as a $\mathbb Z$-module is free follows from the fundamental theorem of arithmetic: every integer greater than 1 either is prime itself or is the product of prime numbers, and this product is unique, up to the order of the factors.

You need to apply it twice: once to the numerator, once to the denominator, assuming they are coprime.

As Hagen von Eitzen and others have noted, the multiplicative group $\mathbb Q^\times$ isn't free, because $-1$ has finite order: $(-1)^2 = 1$.

Comment: But $\Bbb Q^\times$ is certainly not free (in contrast to $\Bbb Q_{>0}$)

Comment: My problem is to find the basis to generate the negative rationals... The function $\psi: \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Q^*}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q^*}$ is $(z,q)\mapsto q^z$, right?

Comment: @rgm $\Bbb Q^*$ has torsion, so it is not free.

Comment: It can't be that $\;\Bbb Q^*\;$ is a free abelian group = free $\;\Bbb Z\,-$ module, since it has a finite order non-trivial element: $\;-1\;$ .

Comment: Excellent observation, @DonAntonio! Thank you! :)

Comment: The body of the question said "positive integers," so I changed the title.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The body of the question also mentions simply "the group of nonzero rational numbers"

Comment: @DonAntonio Whoops, yep, quite right. I took the inset text to be the actual question, when that was the question OP had solved.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Actually, Musili's book's exercise (34 of chapter 5, I think) first talks about the poisitive rationals, *and then* it asks about the non-zero ones.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, an edit was necessary - the statement is true for positive rationals.